# Debian login screen after updating Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, debian

I just updated Ubuntu 18.04 (just the regular "install pending updates" when i shut down). Now I booted my pc, and was greeted with a debian Login screen. This makes absolutely no sense... Is there a fix, or do i have to revert to previous version? Date of installing the update is 8/23/2018.

Comment: You are not alone.
I wrote what I found here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068395/i-cannot-boot-normally-after-online-update-23-8-2018-from-16-04-to-18-04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. By looking at `/var/log/apt/history.log` I could see the update had removed *ubuntu-session*, *ubuntu-desktop*, *gdm3* and *gnome-shell*.
After reinstalling those, it works fine again (maybe the most recent updates of the Linux kernel to 4.15.0-33 helped too).