# Ubuntu 18.04 stuck after login in purple screen

Tags: gnome, login, freeze, amdgpu

After putting credentials laptop stuck in purple screen ... I have AMD driver so I can't install proprietery driver either... need help

Answer (score 0):

If you installed the online updates on 08.23, then your problem is probably caused by gnome vs amdgpu not working together:

[I cannot boot normally after online update 23.8.2018 from 16.04 to 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068395/i-cannot-boot-normally-after-online-update-23-8-2018-from-16-04-to-18-04/1068416#1068416)

Comment: so, should i just stop using ubuntu or are there other solutions

Comment: if you follow the link I attached to my answer, there you will find a description of how I fixed this.