# Is my system in a consistent state now after failed upgrade from 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS?

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, 18.04

I updated my system on Thursday from 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS and the upgrade failed because of [the dependency mismatch in libmutter-2-0 described in this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068269/failed-update-to-18-04-no-gnome-or-any-desktop). It was in a state where only console login worked.

The next day, an update of libmutter was available, and I installed it with

```
 sudo apt install libmutter-2-0 --reinstall
```

and afterwards I installed the ubuntu desktop with

```
 sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

Now I have a seemingly working system, but is it already in a consitent state? Or are there other steps necessary to take to bring it into a consistent state?

EDIT: Output of `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`:

```
 sudo apt update
 Hit:1 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
 Hit:2 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease             
 Hit:3 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease           
 Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [83,2 kB]    
 Fetched 83,2 kB in 1s (107 kB/s)                                               
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree       
 Reading state information... Done
 1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.

 sudo apt upgrade
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree       
 Reading state information... Done
 Calculating upgrade... Done
 The following packages have been kept back:
   gimp-gmic
 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete output of `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`. If you ever question if your system is stable, be happy that you have excellent backups. If you lack excellent backups, then you are about to learn [Murphy's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy%27s_law) the hard way.

Comment: @user535733: Added the requested outputs

Comment: You can use `sudo apt install -f` to check / repair the packages.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: `sudo apt install -f` (without a package argument) does nothing on my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First clean up everything:

```
sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt autoclean
```

Install `debsums` to be able to create MD5 hashes for all packages that would not have any and generate the MD5 hashes next:

```
sudo apt install debsums
sudo debsums_init
```

Now check them:

```
sudo debsums --all | grep FAILED
```

and if you get an output like below:

```
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal                                   FAILED
/etc/bash.bashrc                                                          FAILED
/etc/skel/.bashrc                                                         FAILED
/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion                                FAILED
/etc/grub.d/40_custom                                                     FAILED
debsums: missing file /etc/init.d/keyboard-setup (from keyboard-configuration package)
debsums: missing file /etc/xdg/autostart/nautilus-autostart.desktop (from nautilus package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/pkg-config-crosswrapper (from pkg-config package)
debsums: missing file /usr/share/pkg-config-dpkghook (from pkg-config package)
/etc/sysctl.conf                                                          FAILED
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cupshelpers/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-35.pyc FAILED
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cupshelpers/__pycache__/config.cpython-35.pyc FAILED
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cupshelpers/__pycache__/cupshelpers.cpython-35.pyc FAILED
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cupshelpers/__pycache__/installdriver.cpython-35.pyc FAILED
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cupshelpers/__pycache__/openprinting.cpython-35.pyc FAILED
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cupshelpers/__pycache__/ppds.cpython-35.pyc FAILED
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cupshelpers/__pycache__/xmldriverprefs.cpython-35.pyc FAILED
debsums: missing file /usr/lib/rhythmbox/plugins/rbzeitgeist/__pycache__/rbzeitgeist.cpython-35.opt-1.pyc (from rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist package)
debsums: missing file /usr/lib/rhythmbox/plugins/rbzeitgeist/__pycache__/rbzeitgeist.cpython-35.pyc (from rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist package)
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic                                            FAILED
```

you're fine **if and only if**:

- for every fail you know that you've changed the configuration yourself (manually or through an application)
- they're just missing files
- they're just cache misses
- and you know why `gimp-gmic` is being held back in your particular case.

Comment: @solsTICe: Urgh... **:-(**  Thanks for the edit! **:-)**